# SQL to HQL with subqueries

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I've read about the lack of support for subqueries with HQL, but anyway, anyone could tell me if this SQL query could be implemented with HQL?

I've already made some testing but with no success...don't know if I'm in the right path...

SQL (working)

```
    SELECT
    foo.id as fooId,
    foo.name AS fooName,
    chan.name AS chanName,
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        foo_lang.VALUE
     FROM
        foo_lang
     WHERE
        foo_lang.foo_id = fooId AND
        foo_lang.lang_id = 1) as EN
    FROM
        foo
    INNER JOIN chan ON foo.chan_id = chan.id
```

HQL (not working)

```
select new
    Map(o.id as id,
        o.name as fooName,
        c.name as chanName,
        (select fl.value from foo_lang fl where fl.id.fId = id and fl.id.lId = 1) as EN)
from
    foo o
    left join o.chan c
```

It gives:

org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [big_decimal : component[lId,rId]]

Is about the subqueries or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see two open brackets, but only one close. Did you try it by fixing it?

Comment: Thanks. Closing bracket added but the problem persists.

Comment: One more question: what is fooId in this expression:  foo_lang.foo_id = fooId AND.

And what if subquery will return more than one row? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed to reproduce you case with little bit different objects, and I don't understant why you need this subquery. AFAIK, logically it will be the same if you join **foo_lang** to **foo**, like this:

```
SELECT
 o.id,
 o.name as fooName,
 c.name as chanName,
 fl.value as EN
FROM foo AS o
LEFT JOIN o.chan AS c
LEFT JOIN o.foo_lang AS fl WITH fl.lang_id = 1
```